# Postman check XML response includes multiple elements and values

Tags: javascript, xml, api, postman

Below is part of a response from an API, there can be around 10 UserGroup blocks in the response. I need to check that the response includes a certain UsergroupType e.g 6, then also check the Users.User.Value is a certain value, I've tried:

```
 pm.test("Body includes UserGroupValue 1 ", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.body("<UserGroupValue>1.00</UserGroupValue>");
});
```

But because there maybe another element with the same value  I can't be sure it's the correct UserGroup block.   I guess I need to check multiple lines and declare these in tests, but I'm not sure how to do this,  Unless there is another way? thanks in advance!!

```
<UserGroup>
    <UserGroupType>1</UserGroupType>
    <UserGroupDescription>Users</UserGroupDescription>
    <UserGroupValue>1.00</UserGroupValue>
    <UserGroupCurrency>USD</UserGroupCurrency>
    <UserGroupISOCurrency>150</UserGroupISOCurrency>
    <UserGroupISOCurrencySymbol>$</UserGroupISOCurrencySymbol>
    <Users>
        <User>
            <UserType>67</UserType>
            <UserDescription>Test</UserDescription>
            <UserValue>1.00</UserValue>
            <UserCurrency>USD</UserCurrency>
            <UserISOCurrency>150</UserISOCurrency>
        </User>
        <User>
            <UserType>15</UserType>
            <UserDescription>Test2</UserDescription>
            <UserValue>1.00</UserValue>
            <UserCurrency>USD</UserCurrency>
            <UserISOCurrency>150</UserISOCurrency>
        </User>
    </Users>
</UserGroup>
<UserGroup>
    <UserGroupType>6</UserGroupType>
    <UserGroupDescription>Users2</UserGroupDescription>
    <UserGroupValue>1.00</UserGroupValue>
    <UserGroupCurrency>USD</UserGroupCurrency>
    <UserGroupISOCurrency>150</UserGroupISOCurrency>
    <UserGroupISOCurrencySymbol>$</UserGroupISOCurrencySymbol>
    <Users>
        <User>
            <UserType>78</UserType>
            <UserDescription>Test</UserDescription>
            <UserValue>1.00</UserValue>
            <UserCurrency>USD</UserCurrency>
            <UserISOCurrency>150</UserISOCurrency>
        </User>
        <User>
            <UserType>15</UserType>
            <UserDescription>Test2</UserDescription>
            <UserValue>1.00</UserValue>
            <UserCurrency>USD</UserCurrency>
            <UserISOCurrency>150</UserISOCurrency>
        </User>
    </Users>
</UserGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* try something like this but it has its limitations, in terms of the way your XML data is returned:

```
let convertedData = xml2Json(pm.response.text())

pm.test("Check UserGroup data", function () {
    pm.expect(convertedData.UserGroup.UserGroupType).to.equal("1");
    pm.expect(convertedData.UserGroup.UserGroupValue).to.equal("1.00");
});
```

There's some more information about working with XML responses here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xC4QQCQDDDk

Comment: Appreciate your response.  I get  
Check UserGroup data | TypeError: Cannot read property 'UserGroupType' of undefined

Comment: Do I need to give the full path to the UserGroupType?

Comment: Can you update/edit the original question with the things you have tried and expand on any details please, it's different to answer via comments :)

Comment: Ok apologies Danny,  I get the error :  "Check UserGroup data | TypeError: Cannot read property 'UserGroupType' of undefined"

I wasn't sure if because I needed to add the full path to that element, so I've now added the full path, e.g 

<x />
 <y />
  <UserGroup />
   <UserGroupType>1</UserGroupType>

so my test now reads: 

pm.expect(convertedData.x.y.z.UserGroup.UserGroupType).to.equal("1");

Now I get the error:  Check UserGroup data | AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 1

Comment: If you have different response data and than the example on the question, it's difficult for people to be able to help you. Try using the `console.log()` statement to see what's getting returned for a certain path.

Comment: Hey, I've never used console.log() but after using it I can see where I needed to be and now I have my test working so thumbs ups from me!!!  I needed to use an array because the blocks had the same element names, thanks for your help on this one Danny.